# Creating custom cache table in install file with Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

In Drupal 7, you could create a custom cache table by doing something like this:

```
$schema['custom_table'] = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('system','cache');
```

As the function is deprecated in Drupal 8 please could you help me find equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Follow the Drupal 8 Design

In Drupal 8, the [Cache API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/cache/8.2.x) provides multiple [cache backend](https://docs.acquia.com/article/drupal-8-cache-backend). Cache got separated into different **"Cache Bin"**. If it is [DatabaseBackend](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Cache!DatabaseBackend.php/class/DatabaseBackend/8.2.x), there will be different tables for different bins. But it is up to the backend how to implement your Cache Bin.

So you are not going to directly interact with database tables like you do in Drupal 7. You need to invoke the [CacheBackendInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Cache!CacheBackendInterface.php/interface/CacheBackendInterface/8.2.x) implementation provided by Drupal 8 core.

### Create Custom Cache Bin

Let's say you're going to create a module `mymodule` with a custom cache bin `mycache`. You should define your custom module's dependency on CacheBackendInterface with your custom bin name.

In your `mymodule.services.yml` file, there should be a section like this:

```yaml
cache.mycache:
  class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface
  tags:
    - { name: cache.bin }
  factory: cache_factory:get
  arguments: [mycache]
```

Then by installing the module, the dependency to the cache bin will be passed to the `CacheBackendInterface` implementation. The requested cache bin will be created.

### Use the Cache Bin

Then you may use your custom cache bin like this:

```php
<?php

$data = NULL;
if ($cache = \Drupal::cache('mycache')->get($cid)) {
  $data = $cache->data;
}
else {
  $data = mymodule_complicated_calculation();
  \Drupal::cache('mycache')->set($cid, $data);
}

?>
```

### Force Using Database Backend

If you want to force your cache to use database, you can add this to your setting file:

```php
 $settings['cache']['bins']['mycache'] = 'cache.backend.database';
```

---

## If You Insist ... Try This

OK. If you insist to get the raw schema of DatabaseBackend, you should get it from the public method `schemaDefinition()` of [Drupal\Core\CacheDatabaseBackend](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Cache!DatabaseBackend.php/class/DatabaseBackend/8.2.x).

You can call it like this:

```php
<?php

$schema = \Drupal::cache()->schemaDefinition();

?>
```

Comment: Good to know. And will you please help upvote this and marking this as the correct answer (by clicking the "tick" sign near the title)? I need this to help doing the Drupal 8 documentation here. Thanks!

Comment: Also, curious, which solution did you use?

Comment: I actually used the cache bins but all 3 methods you mentioned work.